# Displaying game options then comparing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a game of Rock paper scissors I want to show the computers choices 1 by 1, then let the user input a series of choices to beat the computers sequence.

Here is what i have so far:

```
var computersHand = [];

function playSimon(){
    startClock(); //Start Timer
    startGame();
}

function  startGame() {
  numOfRounds++;

  for(var i = 0; i < numOfRounds; i++){
     var tmpGame = getComputersMoveSimon();
     computersHand[i] = tmpGame;

     getusersmove();

  }
}

function getUsersMove() {
    console.log(computersHand.toString()); //Testing the array
    document.getElementById("playOptionsSimon").style.display = 'block';
    startGame();
}

function getComputersMoveSimon() {
    var tmpNum = Math.random();

    if(tmpNum < .33){
        return "Rock";
    }
    else if(tmpNum < .66){
        return "Paper";
    }
    else{
        return "Scissors";
    }
}

<div id="playOptionsSimon" style="display: none">
    <h4>Choose your move to beat the computer!</h4>
    <img id="clickedRockSimon" src="img/rock.jpg" onclick="playSimonRock()" />
    <img id="clickedPaperSimon" src="img/paper.jpg" onclick="playSimonPaper()"/>
    <img id="clickedScissorsSimon" src="img/scissors.jpg" onclick="playSimonScissors()" />
</div>
```

The problem I am having is it only shows 1 item in the array, then how can I store the users input only UPto the number of rounds.

Comment: This example code appears to be missing a number of things. Where is `numOfRounds` defined?

Comment: Are are defined at the top of my program with all of my program variables

Comment: those would be important to include in the example code you posted.

Comment: What is the call to getusersmove(); in the startGame function? the function name is not the same as the other function name (uppercase letters), but if you do that you will have an infinite loop there.

Comment: I also do not see `playSimonRock()`, `playSimonPaper()`, or `playSimonScissors()` defined.

Comment: @Twisty I have not made those yet, was not sure if that was best route to go

Comment: My idea was to call the startgame to get a new computers move and store that in array. Then store a global array of computers move, and compare it against a local users array. If they match lets add a new element to the computershand then compare again

Comment: @Jona the code is uncomplete, so it's really hard to help. You have incorrect code as well... plus code that is creating an infinite loop, by calling `startGame()` in multiple ways. You will want to understand the flow and logic of your goal so that you can then build the code for it.

Comment: My logic was in the comment above. I mostly created those infiinte loops to see if it was adding to the array which is reinalizes the array each time for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```js
var numOfRounds = 0;
var rounds = [];
var computersHand;
var clockTime;


function startClock() {
  clockTime = new Date();
}

function playSimon() {
  startClock(); //Start Timer
  console.log("Start Game: " + clockTime.toString());
  startGame();
}

function startGame() {
  numOfRounds++;

  var cm = getComputersMoveSimon();
  console.log("Round: " + numOfRounds + ", Computer: " + cm);

  rounds.push({
    round: numOfRounds,
    start: clockTime,
    end: null,
    computer: cm,
    user: null,
    winner: null
  })

  $("#playOptionsSimon").show();
}

function getUsersMove(sel) {
  var i = rounds.length - 1;
  console.log("Round " + rounds[i].round + ", User: " + sel);
  rounds[i].user = sel;
  rounds[i].end = new Date();
  rounds[i].winner = getWinner(rounds[i].computer, rounds[i].user);
  return rounds[i];
}

function getComputersMoveSimon() {
  var tmpNum = Math.random();
  var sel = "Scissors";

  if (tmpNum < .33) {
    sel = "Rock";
  } else if (tmpNum < .66) {
    sel = "Paper";
  }

  return sel;
}

function getWinner(compMove, userMove) {
  var winner = "Computer";
  if (compMove == userMove) {
    return "Draw";
  }
  switch (true) {
    case (compMove == "Rock" && userMove == "Paper"):
      winner = "User";
      break;
    case (compMove == "Scissors" && userMove == "Rock"):
      winner = "User";
      break;
    case (compMove == "Paper" && userMove == "Scissors"):
      winner = "User";
      break;
  }
  return winner;
}

function calcGameTime(s, e) {
  return Math.round((e - s) / 1000);
}

function endGame() {
  var r = rounds[rounds.length - 1];
  var t = calcGameTime(r.start, r.end);
  $("#Results").html("Computer: " + r.computer + " | You: " + r.user + "<br />");
  if (r.winner == "User") {
    $("#Results").append("Round " + r.round + ": You won! Game time: " + t + " seconds. Press Start Game to play again.");
  } else if (r.winner == "Draw") {
    $("#Results").append("Round " + r.round + ": It was a Draw! Game time: " + t + " seconds. Press Start Game to play again.");
  } else {
    $("#Results").append("Round " + r.round + ": Sorry, you lost! Game time: " + t + " seconds. Press Start Game to play again.");
  }
  $("#clickedStartGame").fadeIn();
}

$(function() {
  $("#clickedStartGame").click(function() {
    $("#Results").html("");
    playSimon();
    $(this).hide();
  });
  $(".btn").click(function(e) {
    var s = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log("User Clicked " + s);
    var round = getUsersMove(s);
    console.log(round);
    endGame();
  });
});
```

```css
.btn {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="clickedStartGame">Start Game</button>

<div id="playOptionsSimon" style="display: none;">
  <h4>Choose your move to beat the computer!</h4>
  <img id="Rock" class="btn rock" src="" alt="Rock" />
  <img id="Paper" class="btn paper" src="" alt="Paper" />
  <img id="Scissors" class="btn scissor" src="" alt="Scissors" />
  <br />
  <div id="Results"></div>
</div>
```